# Using Mongo Query, remove specific key (if it exists) from a list of dictionaries

Tags: database, mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am currently using a query to update multiple mongo docs at once.
The data structure is as shown:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60742505d67349ff473531ca"),
    "user_id" : "1",
    "md5checksum" : "0x0",
    "metadata" : {
        "tag_ids" : [
            "566bb8b92121069b34ae448a",
            "566bb8b82121069b34ae4481"
        ],
        "category_id" : "60640fa4dc84ef2ed9f6a1c9",
        "custom_metadata" : [
            {
                "key_id" : "5a79e24b7fda236fbebe1912",
                "type" : "freetext",
                "value" : [
                    "kiShaan",
                    "desh"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key_id" : "6052e700dc84ef7d492b5d30",
                "multi_value_exists" : true,
                "type" : "freetext",
                "value" : [
                    "kiShaan",
                    "desh",
                    "Fauji",
                    "Saad"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "description" : "test bulk archive",
        "slug" : "a-alpha"
    }
}
```

And the query to update them are:

```
db.example.update({"metadata.custom_metadata.key_id":"6052e700dc84ef7d492b5d30"},{"$set":{"metadata.custom_metadata.$.value":["kiShaan","desh","Fauji","Saad"],"metadata.custom_metadata.$.type":"freetext"}},{"multi":true})
```

The issue I am facing is that there would be **certain** docs that have the key "multi_value_exists", not all. While updating using the shown query, I also want to remove that key "multi_value_exists" if it exists using a mongo query itself. Any help would suffice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query

```
db.example.update({"metadata.custom_metadata.key_id":"6052e700dc84ef7d492b5d30"},
{"$set":{"metadata.custom_metadata.$.value":["kiShaan","desh","Fauji","Saad"],"metadata.custom_metadata.$.type":"freetext"},
"$unset": { "multi_value_exists": 1 } },
{"multi":true})
```

Comment: Oh, it was $unset. Totally missed that. I had to use {"$unset" : "metadata.custom_metadata.$.multi_value_exists":1}. It works even if it key is not present in certain docs.  Thanks.